# How do I move text upwards slowly on scroll?

Tags: javascript, text, scroll, intersection-observer

I want to make my text move upwards slowly, on scroll, however the text should remain on screen as I do so. Like lightmatter's website. https://lightmatter.co/, at the traditional computing park

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".scrolling-text");

    const callbackFunction = function(entries) {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                elements.style.opacity = 1;
                window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
            } else {
                elements.style.opacity = 0;
                window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
            }
        });
    };

    const observerOptions = {
        threshold: 0.3
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackFunction, observerOptions);

    elements.forEach(element => {
        observer.observe(element);
    });

    function scrollHandler() {
        var scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
        elements.style.bottom = 20 - (scrollPosition * 0.2) + 'px';
    }

});
```

This did not work, and only manipulated the text